# Python mode hangs on class member comment

Tags: python

Emacs is freezing when trying to insert a class attribute comment when it's not at the end. E.g.,

```python
class Foo:
   _bar: int
   """Some attribute."""
   _biz: int
   """Another attribute."""
```

I **cannot** edit the above to create the below

```python
class Foo:
   _bar: int
   """Some attribute."""
   _bat: int
   """I can type the 2 quotes but the 3rd causes a freeze!!"""
   _biz: int
   """Another attribute."""
```

but I **can** add one at the very end, e.g.,

```python
class Foo:
   _bar: int
   """Some attribute."""
   _biz: int
   """Another attribute."""
   _winning: int
   """This works!"""
```

This happens both with and without the `-Q` option.
Has anyone else ever seen this behavior? Toubleshooting steps are much appreciated!!

- OS: MacOS 12.6
- Emacs Version: 28.2 installed via Homebrew

Output of `brew info --cask emacs`:

```
==> emacs: 28.2
https://emacsformacosx.com/
/usr/local/Caskroom/emacs/28.2 (5 files, 275KB)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/emacs.rb
==> Name
Emacs
==> Description
Text editor
==> Artifacts
Emacs.app (App)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -> emacs (Binary)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ebrowse (Binary)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient (Binary)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/etags (Binary)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/man/man1/ebrowse.1.gz (Manpage)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/man/man1/emacs.1.gz (Manpage)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/man/man1/emacsclient.1.gz (Manpage)
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/man/man1/etags.1.gz (Manpage)
==> Analytics
install: 3,531 (30 days), 10,356 (90 days), 43,386 (365 days)
```

**Update**: Rolling back to Emacs 27.2 resolves this issue.

Comment: Update: Rolling back to Emacs 27.2 resolves this issue

Comment: I added your comment to the question (where all relevant information should be added - comments are for questions and minor clarifications). If you want, you can delete the comment now.

Comment: i'm also seeing an issue with python and quotes in 28.2, although not exactly the same scenario. found this bug report: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2023-01/msg01702.html

Comment: Starting Emacs with the `--debug-on-error` might help trace the problem. There are other options for triggering debugging too, to `--debug-on-{event,message,next-call,quit,signal}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the actual issue which causes this but since this question I've moved to Emacs 29 installed via Homebrew's `emacs-plus@29` and am not seeing the issue.